# How add virtual property to sealed class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, virtual, sealed

I wrote a class in c# which inherits TextBox and now I want to add a virtual property to it:

```
    public virtual Color WatermarkColor
    {
        private get { return _watermarkColor; }
        set
        {
            _watermarkColor = value;
            OnEnter(null);
            OnLeave(null);
        }
    }
```

but this error occurred:

> Error 1   'xXx.TextBoxPlus.WaterMark.get' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'xXx.TextBoxPlus'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have declared `TextBoxPlus` as a `sealed` class, so it can't be subclassed. Therefore, the `virtual` specifier is unnecessary because it will never be overridden.

Just remove the `virtual` and you should be fine. (Or remove the `sealed` from the class definition if you intend to subclass it later.)